# count rows for three levels(L1, L2, L3) column and status P for every month in a year

Tags: mysql

I have a table like t[image]his table:

So I want to count the rows for three levels (L1,L2,L3) as column and status is P for every month in a year.

i was solve single query.

SELECT year(date) as year, date as month, (SELECT COUNT(level_id)) as L1 FROM        attendance WHERE level_id = 'L1' AND status = 'P' AND year(date) = '2016' GROUP BY date

I want a table like this table :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should give you the result you want.  Just use conditional aggregation along with a `GROUP BY` to count the number of times each type of level appears for a given year and month.

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year,
       MONTH(date) AS month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN level_id = 'L1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS L1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN level_id = 'L2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS L2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN level_id = 'L3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS L3
FROM yourTable
WHERE status = 'P' AND
      YEAR(date) = 2016
GROUP BY YEAR(date),
         MONTH(date)
```

As a tip for future reference, if you wanted to avoid ordering by two separate columns, you could have also used this:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')
```

This would give you a single column containing the year and month, and might make your query a bit less verbose.

Comment: @shalder Sorry, I updated, I did not see your original `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT year(date) as year, date as month, (SELECT COUNT(level_id)) as L1 FROM attendance WHERE level_id = 'L1' AND      Hey!! here is my where clause     " status = 'P' "    AND year(date) = '2016' GROUP BY date

Comment: @shalder I have restricted the query to only the 2016 year now.

Comment: @shalder Reload your page, I already gave you the query you requested.